# Why are Random Unknown Projects Being Created Under my Google Cloud Platform Organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

New projects are showing up under my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) organization:

```sh
gcloud projects list --format='table(name:label=NAME, projectId:label=PROJECT_ID)'

#=>

NAME              PROJECT_ID
. . .             . . .
My First Project  primeval-jet-xxxxxx
My First Project  thermal-imprint-xxxxxx
My First Project  hip-weaver-xxxxxx
. . .             . . .
```

where `xxxxxx` represent random alphanumeric characters.

I am not part of any GCP groups.  I am the owner of my organization, which *should* have just one project.

I've tried to add a billing account on GCP and it has failed multiple times because of suspicious activity on my account.

I have 2FA enabled and changed my password multiple times.  The problem still persists.

What should I do?

Comment: @ArdenSmith 
google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation
MY-ORGANISATION-EMAIL has executed google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation on acat.p2-1091069246719-2c575822-53d0-4aa8-8c20-cef2e9464714
19:43
google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation
MY-ORGANISATION-EMAIL has executed google.longrunning.Operations.GetOperation on acat.p2-1091069246719-2c575822-53d0-4aa8-8c20-cef2e9464714
19:43
google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService
MY-ORGANISATION-EMAIL has executed google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService on cloudapis.googleapis.com
My email appears as creator.

Comment: You should contact Google Cloud Support and ask for help. Please don't ever share screenshots of Console. Doing so can expose personal information that may lead to this type of behavior. It's possible that you've inadvertently added another identity to your Organization or that you've leaked bearer credentials and enabled someone to do this. Are you able to inspect the permissions for those projects? You can visit `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=primeval-jet-xxxxxx` for example and identify what is listed with "Role" of "Owner". Don't share the results here.

Comment: Edit your question with those details.

Comment: @DazWilkin I checked the IAM page and it shows that I am the owner of that project.

Comment: Are any other suspicious looking accounts listed? You can ignore any that include `gserviceaccount.com`. This confirms that your credentials are being used but it doesn't necessarily suggest that they've been stolen. Are you doing anything else that could involve the creation of these projects on your behalf? I continue to encourage you to contact Cloud Support. Google is motivated to stop this type of behavior too if it is indeed nefarious.